# ¿Cómo leer un operador matemático?

Tags: java

He usado:

```
a =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Para leer un entero "a". Pero, ¿cómo leer o ingresar Op. Matemáticos `+ - * /`?

Comment: No vas a poder hacerlo de manera tan directa. ¿Cómo de compleja es la entrada de datos? ¿Qué se admite además de números y operadores? ¿Cuántos operadores?

Comment: Me piden ingresar dos enteros y un operador (+, -, *, /) y determinar el resultado de aplicar el operador a dichos números. Ya he usado Buff para mi entrada de datos enteros, sólo necesito saber cómo ingresar uno de esos operadores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        int parametro1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String op = br.readLine();
        int parametro2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        switch(op){
            case "+":
                System.out.println(parametro1 + parametro2);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(parametro1 - parametro2);
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println(parametro1 * parametro2);
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println(parametro1 / parametro2);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Pensé que se tenía que utilizar char (para la entrada de operadores), tenía esa duda. Muchas gracias!